# Find If a Ray Intersects a Voxel Without Marching

Tags: algorithm, geometry, voxel

I'm well aware of the marching / DDA algorithms, but instead I would like to be able to do a per voxel-ray pair check, in constant time, without having to "march" through the voxel space. How would I go about this?

To be clear, I am not trying to find the *first* voxel a ray intersects, but rather, given a ray and a voxel, determine if that voxel's cell even lies within the ray's path.

Comment: I am afraid this is impossible. The voxels are independent and there is no shortcut. If it was possible to predict on which voxel you land without marching, that would just mean that the voxel representation was inappropriate.

Comment: I'm well aware that it's not possible to find the *first* intersected voxel without marching, and that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm simply trying to find if *a* voxel is ever intersected by the infinitely long ray, assuming nothing can ever block the ray. I realize my original language was unclear, so I've edited the question to better communicate this distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ray is `P = O + t D`, where `P`, `O`, `D` are vectors and `t` a positive real. There is an intersection with the voxel `[x,y,z]x[x+1,y+1,z+1]` if the system below has a solution:

```
x < Ox + t Dx < x + 1
y < Oy + t Dy < y + 1
z < Oz + t Dz < z + 1
0 < t
```

which we rewrite for brevity (with `x' = (x - Ox) / Dx` ...)

```
x' < t < x"
y' < t < y"
z' < t < z"
 0 < t
```

If `Dx < 0`, the inequalities must be reversed. If `Dx == 0`, the inequation degenerates in `x < Ox < x + 1`, which can be directly decided.

Repeat the same discussion for all three axis and check if all bracketings are compatible.

For instance, for `Dx, Dy, Dz > 0`, you must have

```
max(0, x', y', z') < min(x", y", z").
```

There are 27 sign combinations to be considered, which are separated in three cascaded three-way comparisons.

---

As a micro-optimization, you can rescale the last inequality by `Dx Dy Dz` and simplify, to trade divisions for (faster) multiplications.

---

If many rays miss the voxel, you can speed-up the process a little by using the bounding sphere. Assuming that the voxel center is `C`, voxel radius `R` and the vector `D` is normalized, the pre-test is

```
(OC x D)² < R²
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Ray Box (AABB) Intersection algorithm.

[Arbitrary one](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~awilliam/box/)

If you need intersection coordinates, then choose 3D line clipping algorithm

Comment: I certainly could, though those are generalized to any AABBs. In my case I have the extra constraint of a uniform grid with integer indices, and I would like to believe that there is a more efficient option than constructing an AABB out of each grid cell to be tested against and feeding it to an AABB algorithm.

Comment: I don't believe that integers give some gain. More important - do possible precalculations for given ray and grid (like Optimized Algo section in linked paper)